# Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems, gemfile

Error setting up my database when trying to clone this repo (https://github.com/ssaffa38/prelaunchr) and running it on my local server. Where I'm getting is stuck is where it is asking to setup local database.

The code  I'm putting in is:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

The error I keep getting is:

> Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

What I've tried to do is update my Gemfile, but still have no luck.

Here is the full error report in my terminal (not sure if this is where I have to post this...):

Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: here is my Gemfile

```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.5.3'

gem 'activeadmin', '1.0.0'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '~> 4.1.2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'unicorn'

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2.2'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 5.0.7'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.4.2'
  gem 'rspec-mocks', '3.4.1'
  gem 'test-unit', '~> 3.0'
  gem "dotenv-rails"
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'rails_serve_static_assets'
end
```

Update: here is my output as code

```js
Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:6:in `establish_connection'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:76:in `establish_master_connection'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:14:in `create'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:278:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each_current_configuration'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"prelaunchr_development", "host"=>"localhost"}
Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:6:in `establish_connection'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:76:in `establish_master_connection'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:14:in `create'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:278:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:277:in `each_current_configuration'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"prelaunchr_test", "host"=>"localhost"}
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:109:in `create_current'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: can't activate pg (~> 0.15), already activated pg-1.2.3. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:175:in `spec'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:109:in `create_current'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Update: I tried deleting and reinstalling my PostgreSQL app. When I did, I'm now getting a different error when I run:

```html
bundle exec rake db:create 
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

This is what I get:

```js
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 0x0009): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file) - /Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.bundle
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `require'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-2.2.31/lib/bundler.rb:175:in `require'
/Users/sahrsaffa/Downloads/prelaunchr-master/config/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/Downloads/prelaunchr-master/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/Users/sahrsaffa/Downloads/prelaunchr-master/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/sahrsaffa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: @dbugger - I did. This was the confirmation message I received: 

Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 86 gems now installed.
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

Comment: I just tried that and I'm getting the same results. I'm going to add my Gemfile to the question to show exactly what I did to update it.

Comment: Please format the output as code.

Comment: sounds good @DaveNewton - just did.

Comment: Two suggestions, first make sure that postgress is actually installed. You should be able to run psql from the command line and get a psql prompt. If not then figure out how to install it for your OS. If on a Mac the easiest way is to install the postgres app. Second suggestion is to delete your Gemfile.lock and run bundle install again.

Comment: You were correct about my Postgres not being correctly installed. I've since then deleted it and reinstalled it. Now when I run psql on the command line I get a prompt (before I didn't get one). Now, I'm getting a similar, but different error report which I've tried to document correctly in the questionnaire.

Comment: The error is indicating that Postgres is still not properly installed. libpq is the C application programmer's interface to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @max. Any idea on how I should trouble shoot? Should I uninstall and re-install Postgres again?

Comment: Depends completely on the OS and package mangager unfortunately.

Comment: macOS Monterey Apple M1 
Homebrew is my default package manager but I went directly to the Postgres website to install Postgres